# Replicating the same POST request (inspected in DeveloperTools) fails to scrape data

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, python-requests

I'm trying to grab the tabular data from this page without using `BeautifulSoup` to parse the resulted HTML:
https://finance.vietstock.vn/ket-qua-giao-dich/vietnam.aspx?tab=thong-ke-gia&exchange=1&code=-19

Looking at DeveloperTools, I found the script `KQGDThongKeGiaStockPaging`, apparently it's a POST request to the url: https://finance.vietstock.vn/data/KQGDThongKeGiaStockPaging (which shows nothing if I just copy/paste to a browser).

I copy the request header, the payload, run the POST request - and I always get back a response whose text is the content of the url https://finance.vietstock.vn/data/KQGDThongKeGiaStockPaging which basically says: `there's nothing here`.

Tried ChatGPT, searched stackoverflow questions. Wondered if I couldn't do it because the data was dynamically loaded (I'm new to this so don't really understand the term) and I might have needed a VerificationToken on the fly. So I tried - in one session - to make a request to the url to get the token, copy that to the payload and run again - still didn't work (always get the content `there's nothing here`).

I know I can use `BeautifulSoup` to read the table from HTML or even `selenium`, but would like to keep it simple with GET/POST request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Function to extract __RequestVerificationToken from the page
def extract_verification_token(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    token_input = soup.find('input', {'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})
    if token_input:
        return token_input['value']
    return None

# URL and initial payload
url = "https://finance.vietstock.vn/data/KQGDThongKeGiaStockPaging"
initial_payload = {
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "catID": 1,
    "stockID": -19,
    "fromDate": "2023-12-07",
    "toDate": "2024-01-07"
}

# Add headers to simulate a legitimate browser request
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
    "Referer": "https://finance.vietstock.vn/ket-qua-giao-dich/vietnam.aspx?tab=thong-ke-gia&exchange=1&code=-19",
}

# Make the initial GET request with headers
response = requests.get("https://finance.vietstock.vn/ket-qua-giao-dich/vietnam.aspx?tab=thong-ke-gia&exchange=1&code=-19", headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    verification_token = extract_verification_token(response.text)
    if verification_token:
        # Update the payload with the verification token
        initial_payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = verification_token

        # Make the actual POST request with the updated payload and headers
        response = requests.post(url, data=initial_payload, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            # Now 'data' contains the tabular data, and you can process it as needed
            print(data)
        else:
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
            print(response.text)
    else:
        print("Verification token not found.")
else:
    print(f"Error fetching the page: {response.status_code}")
```

Comment: I can't visit the original URL in my browser.
Is there a typo? or maybe we can't visit from United States?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I just tried with a VPN for North America and could access the website: https://finance.vietstock.vn/ket-qua-giao-dich/vietnam.aspx?tab=thong-ke-gia&exchange=1&code=-19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from the site you need to get the cookies from the server **plus** get the verification cookie from the HTML too:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.vietstock.vn/ket-qua-giao-dich/vietnam.aspx?tab=thong-ke-gia&exchange=1&code=-19"
api_url = "https://finance.vietstock.vn/data/KQGDThongKeGiaStockPaging"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(
        {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
        }
    )

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    token = soup.select_one('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]')["value"]

    payload = {
        "page": "1",
        "pageSize": "20",
        "catID": "1",
        "stockID": "-19",
        "fromDate": "2023-12-07",
        "toDate": "2024-01-07",
        "__RequestVerificationToken": token,
    }

    data = s.post(api_url, data=payload).json()
    print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[[{'CloseIndex': 1154.68, 'PriorIndex': 1150.72, 'Change': 3.96, 

...
```

Comment: Awesome, simple yet works like a charm. Many thanks. I'm a little struggling to see what it does differently than my code. Could you please point out the piece that I was missing? Is that the part where the token retrieving & data scraping were put under one "session"? Thanks.

Comment: @hq_bk You're not using session or `cookies=` parameter and the verification token needs to be set in cookies too (+ in payload)

Comment: I see, thanks. If I could ask one more favor, what's the alternative that explicitly sets cookies? How would the code look like?

Comment: @hq_bk There's parameter `cookies=` in `requests.get`/`requests.post` (like `headers=` or `data=` ...)